# How do you change the behaviour of a mocked import in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am having trouble changing the behaviour of a mocked module in Jest. I want to mock different behaviours to test how my code will act under those differing circumstances. I don't know how to do this because calls to `jest.mock()` are hoisted to the top of the file, so I can't just call `jest.mock()` for each test. Is there a way to change the behaviour of a mocked module for one test?

```javascript
jest.mock('the-package-to-mock', () => ({
    methodToMock: jest.fn(() => console.log('Hello'))
}))

import * as theThingToTest from './toTest'
import * as types from './types'

it('Test A', () => {
    expect(theThingToTest.someAction().type).toBe(types.SOME_TYPE)
})

it('Test B', () => {
    // I need the-package-to-mock.methodToMock to behave differently here
    expect(theThingToTest.someAction().type).toBe(types.OTHER_TYPE)
})
```

Internally, as you can imagine, `theThingToTest.someAction()` imports and uses `the-package-to-mock.methodToMock()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change mock implementation on a per single test basis \[Jestjs\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790927/how-to-change-mock-implementation-on-a-per-single-test-basis-jestjs)

Comment: This is the best answer that I found
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68398254/9331978

Answer (score 232, accepted):

After you've mocked the module and replaced the `methodToMock` with a spy, you need to import it. Then, at each test, you can change the behaviour of `methodToMock` by calling the [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) spy method.

```javascript
jest.mock('the-package-to-mock', () => ({
    methodToMock: jest.fn()
}))

import { methodToMock } from 'the-package-to-mock'

it('Test A', () => {
    methodToMock.mockImplementation(() => 'Value A')
    // Test your function that uses the mocked package's function here.
})

it('Test B', () => {
    methodToMock.mockImplementation(() => 'Value B')
    // Test the code again, but now your function will get a different value when it calls the mocked package's function.
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, it works like a charm :)

Comment: What if `methodToMock` is a constant property instead?

Comment: Why would you need to mock a constant value. Anyway, just replace `jest.fn()` with the value. Also no need to `import` the module then.

Comment: I get mockImplementation() is not a function when I attempt this method.

Comment: `mockImplementation` will be undefined only if you forget to assign it to `jest.fn()`.  I just tested

Comment: If you get the mockImplementation is undefined error make sure that your function in jest.mock is wrapped in jest.fn(). For example: methodToMock: jest.fn((x) => x + 1)

Comment: when importing es module, don't forget to add `__esModule: true` to the mocked object

Comment: What if the method to mock is the actual constructor? Can I require the actual module only in some tests?

Comment: What if it's not a method, but a constant?

Comment: Wow. I've learnt something new today. I didnt know you have to setup the mocking before importing the module. After 3 hours fidgeting. Thx

Comment: You should not have to mock before an import any more as jest hoists the `jest.mocks` now to my understanding. This causes an issue though if you try to create a const outside of the mock to a mocked function to check if that's been called and to provide proper typing. You will need to defer the call to the mocked function. Something like: `const mockedFn = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('url'); jest.mock('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner', () => { return { getSignedUrl: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockedFn()) } })`

Comment: you saved my life, I was going crazy over this

Answer (score 17):

I use the following pattern:

```
'use strict'

const packageToMock = require('../path')

jest.mock('../path')
jest.mock('../../../../../../lib/dmp.db')

beforeEach(() => {
  packageToMock.methodToMock.mockReset()
})

describe('test suite', () => {
  test('test1', () => {
    packageToMock.methodToMock.mockResolvedValue('some value')
    expect(theThingToTest.someAction().type).toBe(types.SOME_TYPE)

  })
  test('test2', () => {
    packageToMock.methodToMock.mockResolvedValue('another value')
    expect(theThingToTest.someAction().type).toBe(types.OTHER_TYPE)
  })
})
```

Explanation:

You mock the class you are trying to use on test suite level, make sure the mock is reset before each test and for every test you use mockResolveValue to describe what will be return when mock is returned

Comment: Without the reset, the other solution wasn't working for me! thanks

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

E.g.

`the-package-to-mock.ts`:

```
export function methodToMock() {
  return 'real type';
}
```

`toTest.ts`:

```
import { methodToMock } from './the-package-to-mock';

export function someAction() {
  return {
    type: methodToMock(),
  };
}
```

`toTest.spec.ts`:

```
describe('45006254', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('test1', () => {
    jest.doMock('./the-package-to-mock', () => ({
      methodToMock: jest.fn(() => 'type A'),
    }));
    const theThingToTest = require('./toTest');
    expect(theThingToTest.someAction().type).toBe('type A');
  });

  it('test2', () => {
    jest.doMock('./the-package-to-mock', () => ({
      methodToMock: jest.fn(() => 'type B'),
    }));
    const theThingToTest = require('./toTest');
    expect(theThingToTest.someAction().type).toBe('type B');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/45006254/toTest.spec.ts
  45006254
    ✓ test1 (2016 ms)
    ✓ test2 (1 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 toTest.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.443 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/45006254

Comment: This is good but has only a small drawback, it does not necessarily play nice with ide integration

Comment: @gsouf Which IDE? And what about the integration doesn't work well?

Answer (score 6):

`spyOn` worked best for us. See previous answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361996/1708297

Answer (score 1):

## How to Change Mocked Functions For Different Test Scenarios

In my scenario I tried to define the mock function outside of the `jest.mock` which will return an error about trying to access the variable before it's defined. This is because modern Jest will hoist `jest.mock` so that it can occur before imports. Unfortunately this leaves you with `const` and `let` not functioning as one would expect since the code hoists above your variable definition. Some folks say to use `var` instead as it would become hoisted, but most linters will yell at you, so as to avoid that hack this is what I came up with:

### Jest Deferred Mocked Import Instance Calls Example

This allows us to handle cases like `new S3Client()` so that all new instances are mocked, but also while mocking out the implementation. You could likely use something like `jest-mock-extended` here to fully mock out the implementation if you wanted, rather than explicitly define the mock.

#### The Problem

This example will return the following error:

```
eferenceError: Cannot access 'getSignedUrlMock' before initialization
```

`Test File`

```
const sendMock = jest.fn()
const getSignedUrlMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('signedUrl')

jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-s3', () => {
  return {
    S3Client: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      send: sendMock.mockResolvedValue('file'),
    })),
    GetObjectCommand: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
  }
})

jest.mock('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner', () => {
  return {
    getSignedUrl: getSignedUrlMock,
  }
})
```

#### The Answer

You must defer the call in a callback like so:

```
getSignedUrl: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => getSignedUrlMock())
```

#### Full Example

I don't want to leave anything up to the imagination, although I phaked the `some-s3-consumer` from the actual project, but it's not too far off.

`Test File`

```
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { SomeS3Consumer } from './some-s3-consumer'

const sendMock = jest.fn()
const getSignedUrlMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('signedUrl')

jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-s3', () => {
  return {
    S3Client: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      send: sendMock.mockResolvedValue('file'),
    })),
    GetObjectCommand: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
  }
})

jest.mock('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner', () => {
  return {
    // This is weird due to hoisting shenanigans
    getSignedUrl: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => getSignedUrlMock()),
  }
})

describe('S3Service', () => {
  const service = new SomeS3Consumer()

  describe('S3 Client Configuration', () => {
    it('creates a new S3Client with expected region and credentials', () => {
      expect(S3Client).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        region: 'AWS_REGION',
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
          secretAccessKey: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
        },
      })
    })
  })

  describe('#fileExists', () => {
    describe('file exists', () => {
      it('returns true', () => {
        expect(service.fileExists('bucket', 'key')).resolves.toBe(true)
      })

      it('calls S3Client.send with GetObjectCommand', async () => {
        await service.fileExists('bucket', 'key')

        expect(GetObjectCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
          Bucket: 'bucket',
          Key: 'key',
        })
      })
    })

    describe('file does not exist', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        sendMock.mockRejectedValue(new Error('file does not exist'))
      })

      afterAll(() => {
        sendMock.mockResolvedValue('file')
      })

      it('returns false', async () => {
        const response = await service.fileExists('bucket', 'key')

        expect(response).toBe(false)
      })
    })
  })

  describe('#getSignedUrl', () => {
    it('calls GetObjectCommand with correct bucket and key', async () => {
      await service.getSignedUrl('bucket', 'key')

      expect(GetObjectCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key: 'key',
      })
    })

    describe('file exists', () => {
      it('returns the signed url', async () => {
        const response = await service.getSignedUrl('bucket', 'key')

        expect(response).toEqual(ok('signedUrl'))
      })
    })

    describe('file does not exist', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        getSignedUrlMock.mockRejectedValue('file does not exist')
      })

      afterAll(() => {
        sendMock.mockResolvedValue('file')
      })

      it('returns an S3ErrorGettingSignedUrl with expected error message', async () => {
        const response = await service.getSignedUrl('bucket', 'key')

        expect(response.val).toStrictEqual(new S3ErrorGettingSignedUrl('file does not exist'))
      })
    })
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Andreas answer work well with functions, here is what I figured out using it:

```js
// You don't need to put import line after the mock.
import {supportWebGL2} from '../utils/supportWebGL';


// functions inside will be auto-mocked
jest.mock('../utils/supportWebGL');
const mocked_supportWebGL2 = supportWebGL2 as jest.MockedFunction<typeof supportWebGL2>;

// Make sure it return to default between tests.
beforeEach(() => {
  // set the default
  supportWebGL2.mockImplementation(() => true); 
});

it('display help message if no webGL2 support', () => {
  // only for one test
  supportWebGL2.mockImplementation(() => false);

  // ...
});
```

It won't work if your mocked module is not a function. I haven't been able to change the mock of an exported boolean for only one test :/. My advice, refactor to a function, or make another test file.

```js
export const supportWebGL2 = /* () => */ !!window.WebGL2RenderingContext;
// This would give you: TypeError: mockImplementation is not a function
```

Answer (score -1):

Just jest.mock default values.
1.

```
jest.mock('./hooks/useCustom', () => jest.fn(() => value));
// or
jest.mock('./hooks/useCustom');
```

2. And in the test that you want to override the default value:

```
import useCustom from './hooks/useCustom'

it('test smt else', () => {
  useCustom.mockReturnValueOnce(differentValue)
  // with ts: (useCustom as any).mockReturnValueOnce(differentValue)
  // render hook or component
  // expect(...)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react';
import Component from 'component-to-mock';

jest.mock('component-to-mock', () => jest.fn());

describe('Sample test', () => {
  it('first test', () => {
     Component.mockImplementation(({ props }) => <div>first mock</div>);
  });

  it('second test', () => {
     Component.mockImplementation(({ props }) => <div>second mock</div>);
  });
});
```