# How to clear spies from mock functions in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

How to clear spies from mock functions in Jest? `jest.restoreAllMocks()` works perfectly fine if original function isn't a `jest.fn()`. How to correctly clear all spies from `jest.fn()`? This question might be a duplicate of [How to change mock implementation on a per single test basis [Jestjs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790927/how-to-change-mock-implementation-on-a-per-single-test-basis-jestjs) although my question describes a bit simpler scenario where multiple modules are not involved.

```js
describe('Mock', () => {
  const mock = {
    method1: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false),
  };

  afterEach(() => {
    // none of these clear the spy
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('returns false by default', () => {
    expect(mock.method1()).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('changes return value after applying spy implementation', () => {
    jest.spyOn(mock, 'method1').mockReturnValue(true);

    expect(mock.method1()).toEqual(true);
  });

  // this test fails
  it('resets to original value after each test', () => {
    expect(mock.method1()).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why _are_ you spying on what's already a mock?

Comment: @jonrsharpe
I wanted to change the return value of specific mock function inside each test to test different scenarios. I guess it's fine to change mockReturnValue in each test, but then I guess method1 shouldn't be a jest.fn() from the start? I've used jest.fn() so that I can get to calls of method1 and check call arguments without having to create extra spies just for checking that.

Answer (score 0):

To clear spies from mock functions in Jest, we can use the jest.clearAllMocks() command.

Comment: This doesn't work for my use case, please take a look at the code I've provided.