# Cannot find function when trying to write its mockImplementation

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have my test case file set up like this:

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app");

jest.mock("./addFunc", () => ({
    addNumbers: jest.fn()
}));
...
test("Testing add function with double result", () => {
    addNumbers.mockImplentation((a, b) =>
        return 2 * (a + b));
    let res = await request(app).post("/addNumbers").send({
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    });
    expect(res.body.result).toBe(6);
});
...
test("Testing add function with half result", () => {
    addNumbers.mockImplentation((a, b) =>
        return (a - b) / 2);
    let res = await request(app).post("/addNumbers").send({
        a: 6,
        b: 2
    });
    expect(res.body.result).toBe(2);
});
...
```

The `addNumbers` API I am calling contains `addNumbers` function, which I want to mock with different implementations for different test cases like above. I took help from the most-voted answer of [How to change mock implementation on a per single test basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790927/how-to-change-mock-implementation-on-a-per-single-test-basis)

But as I ran the test case, it threw error inside the test case that `addNumbers` is not defined. However, if I don't write `mockImplementation` inside test case and mock the `addNumbers` on top of the file, then it works fine. But in that case how would I rewrite the mock for a different test case?

I am not able to figure it out because `addNumbers` has already been defined on top of the file.

Comment: You never imported or declared `addNumbers`

Comment: ok, but how do I overwrite/rewrite the mock created at the top of the file with ``jest.mock`` for specific test cases. Is it possible?

Comment: I would move `jest.mock...` inside each test

Comment: Is there any cleaner solution than moving jest.mock inside each test case?

Comment: Just `jest.mock("./addFunc");` (which has to be _outside_ the tests @Konrad, otherwise it doesn't get hoisted) and also `const { addNumbers } = require("./addFunc");` to get access to the test double. Although based on what you've posted you really shouldn't be mocking it - your test is mostly of the test double.

Comment: @Konrad moving jest.mock to each test case doesn't work. I have tried it. In that case, mock function does not have any effect and the original function gets called instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what should be the approach then?

Comment: ... _don't_ mock it. Just write the test with the expectation based on the actual behaviour (presumably `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` -> `{ result: 3 }`). Whatever you're doing you at least need to rename the tests, because the one thing you're **not** doing is _"Testing add function"_ - it's not involved at all, _you've mocked it out_. ([Here's](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/May/23/js-tdd-ohm.html) an article I wrote on a TDD approach to an Express API you might find useful.)

Answer (score 2):

You can import the file you are mocking and then reference addNumbers from within the file, instead of using it directly. Here's an example of your updated code:

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app");
const addFunc = require("./addFunc");

jest.mock("./addFunc", () => ({
    addNumbers: jest.fn()
}));
...
test("Testing add function with double result", () => {
    addFunc.addNumbers.mockImplementation((a, b) =>
        return 2 * (a + b));
    let res = await request(app).post("/addNumbers").send({
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    });
    expect(res.body.result).toBe(6);
});
...
test("Testing add function with half result", () => {
    addFunc.addNumbers.mockImplementation((a, b) =>
        return (a - b) / 2);
    let res = await request(app).post("/addNumbers").send({
        a: 6,
        b: 2
    });
    expect(res.body.result).toBe(2);
});
```

Note: I fixed a typo in the mockImplementation, you lost the "me"

Hope it helps!