# Jest Mock React Component ONLY in some tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

This question is really good: [Jest Mock module per test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006254/jest-mock-module-per-test)

It just don't answer my question on how to only mock it out in one single test and keep the rest using the original component.

That would make sense if I wish to do some mocking for an snapshot but not for the other tests

This is my current attempt

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

jest.mock('components/Photo', () =>
  jest.fn(() => jest.requireActual('components/Photo'))
)
import Photo from 'components/Photo'

import PhotoGrid from '.'

beforeEach(() => {
  Photo.mockReset()
})

test('default renders 9 photos if provided 9', () => {
  const photos = [...Array(9).keys()]
  const { getAllByTestId, debug } = render(<PhotoGrid photos={photos} />)

  debug()
  expect(getAllByTestId(PHOTO_COMP_TEST_ID)).toHaveLength(9)
})

test('renders with masonry grid style', () => {
  Photo.mockImplementation(() => <div />)
  const photos = [...Array(9).keys()]
  const { container, debug } = render(<PhotoGrid photos={photos} />)

  debug()

  expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
    <div>
      ... 
    </div>
  `)
})
```

This is the component to test

```js
import React from 'react'
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-css'
import './index.css'

import Photo from 'components/Photo'

function PhotoGrid({ photos, numberOfPhotos = 9 }) {
  const imgs = photos ? photos.slice(0, numberOfPhotos) : []

  const breakpointColumnsObj = {
    default: 4,
    1300: 3,
    900: 2,
    700: 1,
  }

  return (
    <Masonry
      breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
      className="my-masonry-grid"
      columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
    >
      {imgs &&
        imgs.map(({ id, secret, server, farm }, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="masonry-item">
            <Photo id={id} secret={secret} server={server} farm={farm} />
          </div>
        ))}
    </Masonry>
  )
}

export default PhotoGrid
```

Comment: is that working ?

Answer (score 6):

jest.mock(...) the component you want to mock in one of tests.

Use jest.requireActual(...) to implement default behavior.

Use mockImplementation to implement custom behavior.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

jest.mock('components/Photo')
import Photo from 'components/Photo'

import PhotoGrid from '.'

// This maintains the original implementation for tests. 
// This step is important because if not done, it will
// result in empty render errors.
beforeEach(() => {
  Photo.mockImplementation(jest.requireActual('components/Photo'));
}) 
 

// This test will use original implementation of 'components/Photo'
test('default renders 9 photos if provided 9', () => {
  const photos = [...Array(9).keys()]
  const { getAllByTestId, debug } = render(<PhotoGrid photos={photos} />)

  debug()
  expect(getAllByTestId(PHOTO_COMP_TEST_ID)).toHaveLength(9)
})

// This test will use the mocked implementation of 'components/Photo'
test('renders with masonry grid style', () => {
  Photo.mockImplementation(() => <div />)
  const photos = [...Array(9).keys()]
  const { container, debug } = render(<PhotoGrid photos={photos} />)

  debug()

  expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
    <div>
      ... 
    </div>
  `)
})
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function` when I do this.

Comment: This don't work with mockImplementationOnce.

Comment: This don't work with typescript

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the permission to add comments so I will just leave this here.

I have tried the solution offered by Han Daniels and I was getting the error:

`TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function`.

I have fixed it by adding `.default` after `jest.requireActual('components/Photo')` because Photo is the default export.

So it is: `jest.requireActual('components/Photo').default`

Comment: Thanks dude. I had the same problem. So, does this without default works only to no default exports?