# Mock a TypeScript constant different in every Jest test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I'm struggling to mock a constant with Jest on a per test basis. I have it working with the code below, but the mock is "static" - I can't mock it differently for each test.

Code:

```js
// allowList.ts
export const ALLOW_LIST = {
  '1234': true
};
```

```js
// listUtil.ts
import { ALLOW_LIST } from './allowList.ts';

export const checkList = (id: string) => {
  if (ALLOW_LIST[id]) return true;
  return false;
};
```

Test (working):

```js
// listUtil.test.ts
import { checkList } from './listUtil';

jest.mock('./listUtil', () => {
  return {
    '5678': true
  };
});

test('in list', () => {
  expect(checkList('5678')).toBe(true);
});
test('not in list', () => {
  expect(checkList('1234')).toBe(false);
});
```

What I would like (not working):

```js
// listUtil.test.ts
import { checkList } from './listUtil';

test('in list', () => {
  jest.mock('./listUtil', () => {
    return {
      '5678': true
    };
  });
  expect(checkList('5678')).toBe(true);
});
test('not in list', () => {
  jest.mock('./listUtil', () => {
    return {
      '9123': true
    };
  });
  expect(checkList('1234')).toBe(false);
});
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006254/jest-mock-module-per-test) is very similar and appears to work when mocking functions, but I'm having the same issue as the commenters of the accepted answer. I think I'm just not understanding how Jest performs mocking under the hood. I believe the working version works because the mock is hoisted and basically overwrites the real implementation, but I'm not sure how or if I can achieve that in each test.

I think one option would be to expose the ALLOW_LIST via a function:

```js
// allowList.ts
const ALLOW_LIST = {
  '1234': true
};
export const getAllowList = () => ALLOW_LIST;
```

and mock that, but am wondering if that's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) to mock a module differently for each test.

E.g.

`allowList.ts`:

```
export const ALLOW_LIST = {
  '1234': true,
};
```

`listUtil.ts`:

```
import { ALLOW_LIST } from './allowList';
console.log('ALLOW_LIST: ', ALLOW_LIST);

export const checkList = (id: string) => {
  if (ALLOW_LIST[id]) return true;
  return false;
};
```

`listUtil.test.ts`:

```
describe('65712158', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should in list', () => {
    jest.doMock('./allowList', () => ({ ALLOW_LIST: { 5678: true } }));
    const { checkList } = require('./listUtil');
    expect(checkList('5678')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should not in list', () => {
    jest.doMock('./allowList', () => ({ ALLOW_LIST: { 9123: true } }));
    const { checkList } = require('./listUtil');
    expect(checkList('1234')).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65712158/listUtil.test.ts
  65712158
    ✓ should in list (2517 ms)
    ✓ should not in list (2 ms)

  console.log
    ALLOW_LIST:  { '5678': true }

      at Object.<anonymous> (examples/65712158/listUtil.ts:2:9)

  console.log
    ALLOW_LIST:  { '9123': true }

      at Object.<anonymous> (examples/65712158/listUtil.ts:2:9)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 listUtil.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.03 s
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you! I actually did try this, but was missing the `const { checkList } = require('./listUtil');` statements