# VanillaJS per test mocks

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

I am writing some code, I have a dummy scenario of what I am trying to achieve show below. I have a function that I am testing, that uses functions from the a different module. I want to mock the functions for the imported module. How do I go about doing it?

I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326501/6794188), but the `jest.doMock` function does not work in commonJS - is what I understand. This is for a node backend project.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```js
// helper.js

let add = (a, b) => a + b;
let mult = (a, b) => a * b;

module.exports = { add, sub, mult };
```

```js
// index.js

const { add, mult } = require('./helper');

const add5thenMultiply2 = (a) => {
  const res1 = add(a, 5);
  return mult(res1, 2);
};

module.exports = { add5thenMultiply2 };
```

```js
// index.test.js

const { add5thenMultiply2 } = require('./index');

describe('index', () => {
  it('returns right value', () => {
    const input = 3;
    const expected = 16;
    const result = add5thenMultiply2(input);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });

  it('works with mock', () => {
    // mock add() such that it always returns 100, but for this test only
    const input = 3;
    const expected = 200;
    const result = add5thenMultiply2(input);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) works fine with commonJS. You also need to use [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) to mock `./helper` module partially which means only mock `add` function, keep using the original `mult` function.

E.g.

`helper.js`:

```js
let add = (a, b) => a + b;
let mult = (a, b) => a * b;

module.exports = { add, mult };
```

`index.js`:

```js
const { add, mult } = require('./helper');

const add5thenMultiply2 = (a) => {
  const res1 = add(a, 5);
  return mult(res1, 2);
};

module.exports = { add5thenMultiply2 };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
describe('index', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('returns right value', () => {
    const { add5thenMultiply2 } = require('./index');
    const input = 3;
    const expected = 16;
    const result = add5thenMultiply2(input);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });

  it('works with mock', () => {
    jest.doMock('./helper', () => {
      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('./helper'),
        add: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(100),
      };
    });
    const { add5thenMultiply2 } = require('./index');
    const input = 3;
    const expected = 200;
    const result = add5thenMultiply2(input);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67830139/index.test.js (7.751 s)
  index
    ✓ returns right value (6554 ms)
    ✓ works with mock (2 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 helper.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.308 s
```

Comment: Yup, that worked thanks! It's a shame you have to `require` the function under test in every `it` block, but I can live with that.