# Jest tests affects other tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-jest

I am using Jest with vuejs 2.

When I run the test separetly It succeed, but when I run tests in the whole file It fails.

I tried all solutions proposed to clearMocks and resetMocks ect, but It didn't work with me.

The project is available on [github](https://github.com/amirensit/boticot/tree/103_add_analytics_tab_to_display_data_about_users_traffic_and_intents).

Here is my Code:

```
    // views/analytics.ts
    import { getAnalytics } from '@/client/analytics'; // this method returns a Promise
    
    export default Vue.extend({
    ...
    data() {
      return {
       property1: '',
     }
    },
    mounted() { 
      getAnalytics(this.agentName, size).then((response) => {
        this.property1 = response.propertyName
       })
      }
     })

    // client/analytics.ts
    const getAnalytics = async (agentName: string, size: number): Promise<any> => {
      const response = await axios.get(url, opt);
      _.reverse((response as any).analytics);
      return response;
    };
    
    export {
      getAnalytics,
    };

// analytics.spec.ts
   jest.mock('@/client/analytics', () => ({
        getAnalytics: () => Promise.resolve(mockedData), // mockedData is a JSON object
      }));

   describe ('analytics.vue', () => {
     beforeEach(async () => {
       jest.resetModules();
       jest.clearAllMocks();
       const localVue = createLocalVue();
       localVue.use(ElementUI);
       wrapper = shallowMount(Analytics, {
         localVue,
         mocks: {
           $route,
         },
       });
     comp = wrapper.vm;
    });

     afterEach(() => {
       wrapper.destroy();
     });

     it('test 1', async () => {
        const myProperty = comp.$data.property1;
        expect(myProperty).toEqual('expectedValue');
     })

      it('test 2', async () => {
        // same body as test 1.
      })
})
```

I tried different propositions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007792/6717287) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7136) but It doesn't work with me.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy When I run the test separetly It succeed, but when I run tests in the whole file It fails.

Comment: *the test separetly* - which test? *tests in the whole file* - which tests? There are only 2 tests in the code and both are empty, so they cannot cause problems. *It fails* - fails how? Please, show the exact errors and all the code that is affected. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , currently you're the only person who has all needed information at hand. You have fundamental problem with module mocking but it's unknown if it causes problems or something else.

Comment: @EstusFlask I didn't put the body of tests. It does not matter. The problem is not with their body.

Comment: If you knew what the problem is and where it is, you'd be able to solve it, correct? If you aren't, consider providing users with all necessary information they need to solve your problem. The problem may be not in their bodies exactly but in what happens inside them. Please, provide MCVE and clear problem statement as required by SO rules, otherwise the question can't be answered and can be closed.

Comment: @EstusFlask I updated my question.

Comment: The question still contains no errors and other tests. There are no clues what a possible problem could  be.

Comment: @EstusFlask I added a link to the project on github. You can take a look.

Comment: I'll do. Please, provide the exact error messages as well.

Comment: try to run yarn test Analytics.spec.ts.

Comment: any help here ?!